# IEWebGL with Windows Forms WebBrowser Control

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control, webgl

I have a website which I created using three.js and I have installed IEWebGL on my machine and all is working fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE9. However due to our requirements and the need to integrate with existing Windows Forms software we are now trying to view the website in a WebBrowser control. This is causing problems as although the plugin is installed on the machines version of IE it doesn't seem to work with the WebBrowser and throws the script error:

```
Error: cannot create WebGL context.
```

Which if I remember correctly is just the standard error that IE9 throws when trying to use WebGL without the plugin.

So my question is, Is there any way to include the use of the IEWebGL plugin in the WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems that if you force the website to render in IE9 mode using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

it runs okay as I believe it renders in quirks mode natively.